# Bibliography - Avoid "+" symbol by many authors

Tags: biblatex, biber

I would like to get rid of the "+" symbol generated la lualatex/biber:

[image: pic]

Why? Because every time that I see it, I feel bad, I do not like it aesthetically.

Here the MEW I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Jan1991,
        author     = {Jan, J. and One, Two and Three, Four and Five, Six},
        title      = {Something else},
        publisher  = {Whatever},
        year       = {1991}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\title{Bibliography}
\cite{Jan1991}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Compilation:

```
lualatex -synctex=1  -interaction=nonstopmode example.tex
biber example.bcf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `+` with `\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}`

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Jan1991,
        author     = {Jan, J. and One, Two and Three, Four and Five, Six},
        title      = {Something else},
        publisher  = {Whatever},
        year       = {1991}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%\bibliography{\jobname}

\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

\begin{document}
\title{Bibliography}
\cite{Jan1991}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```